# Log4j2 %rThrowable{full} not prinitng getLocalizedMessage

Tags: log4j2

It seems that the `%rThrowable{full}` pattern will not use `getLocalizedMessage` by default, while the `%Throwable{full}` will out put it.

The `rThrowable{short.localizedMessage}` is not working

My pattern is:

```
<property name="consolelayoutPattern">%-5p %-30.30c{2} %m%n%rThrowable{full}</property>
```

Any suggestion ?!

Answer (score 0):

Please raise an issue on the log4j2 Jira issue tracker: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2